# spring security 3.0.3 custom login form

Tags: spring-security

[This handy link](http://www.mularien.com/blog/2008/07/07/5-minute-guide-to-spring-security/) shows how to make a form that replaces the built-in spring security login form in 2.5.6. Can anyone illuminate the corresponding question for 3.0.3? Something has changed, the old form does not work.

When I click on submit it comes back to the login page with the error flag, and the username changes from what I type to 'null'.

This suggests that the names of the required form fields have changed from j_username and j_password to something else.

I'm also suspicious of

```
<input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"
    <c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">value='<%= 
 session.getAttribute(AuthenticationProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME_KEY) %>'
 </c:if> />
```

since AuthenticationProcessingFilter is deprecated.

And the answer is: **POST** is required now. I wish it had produced that error message the first time.

Comment: What error are you getting? Any stack trace would help. What is the autoconfig you are using?

Comment: Nope, no such change. No change in field names. But there is a huge change in upgrading from 2.x to 3.x as there is a lot of class structure changes too. Can you post any stack trace or exception trace..

Comment: @Tej after I finish some other things, I'll put the custom form back. No stack traces appeared in the log, but I'll try setting the log level to DEBUG and see what I get.

Comment: oh!! oh!! your tag is wrong. You are missing `value=`

Comment: Well, it worked with 2.5.6 :-) What should be value be?

Comment: Try posting your new config or any other details which may help diagnose the issue.